# GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT when using texture with internal format GL_R16_SNORM

Tags: opengl

I am rendering 16bit grayscale images using OpenGL and need to fetch rendered data to buffer without bit depth decimation. My code works perfectly on *Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000*, but on nVidia graphic cards (*NVIDIA Corporation GeForce G 105M/PCIe/SSE2*, *NVIDIA Corporation GeForce GT 640M LE/PCIe/SSE2*) it fails with status **GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT** when I try to render to texture with internal format **GL_R16_SNORM**. It works when I use **GL_R16** format, but I also loose all negative values of rendered texture. With Intel HD Graphics it works with both GL_R16_SNORM and GL_16 values.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16_SNORM, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_SHORT, null);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);
glDrawBuffers(1, new int[] {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0}, 0);
int status = gl.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```

What is reason of GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT status on nVidia cards? Can you advise how to debug this situation? (unfortunately glGetError()==GL_NO_ERROR)

EDIT: After further testing I found out it work also on ATI graphics cards. As [Reto Koradi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3530129/reto-koradi) answered, support in OpenGL version pre 4.4 is manufacturer specific and it seems it works on ATI and Intel cards but not on nVidia cards.

[image: Tested graphic cards]

Comment: None of the `SNORM` formats are required to be supported as render targets in the GL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GL_R16_SNORM` only became a required color-renderable format with OpenGL 4.4.

If you look at the big texture format table for example in the 4.3 spec (starting on page 179), the "color-renderable" field is checked for `R16_SNORM`. But then on page 178, under "Required Texture Formats", `R16_SNORM` is listed as a "texture-only color format". This means that while implementations can support rendering to this format, it is not required.

In the 4.4 spec, the table (starting on page 188) basically says the same. `R16_SNORM` has a checkmark in the column "CR", which means "color-renderable". But the rules were changed. In 4.4 and later, **all** color-renderable formats have to be supported by implementations. Instead of containing lists, the "Required Texture Formats" section on page 186 now simply refers to the table. This is also mentioned in the change log section of the spec.

This means that unless you require at least OpenGL 4.4, support for rendering to this format is indeed vendor/hardware dependent.

Comment: Thanks for perfect answer! I will deal with negative values in shader for all pre 4.4 version and for version 4.4 and newer use my current solution.